# tab or right/left key is used according to the accessibility standard

Tags: jquery, html, css

which key is used for navigating the main menu according to the web accessibility standards.Also please suggest the keys for navigating through the submenu.

Comment: its depend upon the tabindex value of elements...

Comment: refer this link https://www.nngroup.com/articles/keyboard-accessibility/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second listing in a single Google search provided a [tutorial explaining exactly what you are asking](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/menus/application-menus/), written by the W3 which write the Web Content Accessibility Guidelines. Key mappings and all.